# Accessing matched obect in a patern matcher in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm currently doing the course *Functionnal Programming Principles in Scala* on *Coursera* and I've just learned about pattern matching. I'm trying to do something that seems not possible and I was wondering what would be the correct idiom.

Here some code from the course:

```
trait Expr
case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr {
  def next = n + 1 // I've added this method
}
case class Sum(e1: Expr, e2: Expr) extends Expr

def show(e: Expr): String = e match {
  case Number(n) =>  n.toString
  case Sum(l, r) => show(l) + " + " + show(r)
}
```

When you use a pattern matcher, you have access to the arguments of the matched object (like `n` for `Number(n)`) but you can't access the matched object (so `Number(n)`).For instance I would have liked to something like this:

```
  case Number(n) =>  'referenceToMatchedObject'.next
```

I know I can do `case Number(n) =>  Number(n).next` but it's not elegant.

Maybe I'm still thinking too mush in OO-style but I whould found it nice to be able to add specific functions that could be applied on the matched object.

Another example: let's say I've got an `Animal Trait/Abstract Class` and a `Cat class`. The `Cat class` is the only one with the function `climbTree`. In a pattern matcher I want to make the cat climb the tree.

What would be the proper Scala-functional way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
def show2(e: Expr): String = e match {
  case n @ Number(1) => n.next.toString
  case n : Number => n.next.toString
  case Sum(l, r) => show(l) + " + " + show(r)
}
```

Comment: Ok cool so I can match on type. But I can't match on Number(1) and still have access to the acutal object? (This might not make sense to be able to in the first place)

Comment: You can do that like this: case n @ Number(1) => n.next.toString

Comment: Yep that's it! I've just finished reading the official documentation on Pattern Matching and there is no mention of such binding operator http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html.html